# How to make en0, en1 persistent?

Tags: macos, xdebug

I am developing a web app in Mac, I am setting remote_host of xdebug to my local ip address of mac, en0, or en01

I can debug normally, and xdebug can communicate well with my Mac from within a docker container.

However, if I restarted my Mac, I will have to set the new en0, or en1 address to xdebug.remote_host settings, otherwise, I will not be able to debug.

How can I make en0, en1 static? why do they change each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why it changes, but you may want to consider enabling [xdebug.remote_connect_back](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_connect_back). This will over-ride the explicit remote_host IP address and allow xdebug to connect back to your IDE no matter what it's IP address is. This is a more dynamic configuration and sounds like it will work well in your situation.